# Do the profiles for search results apply only to advanced search?

Tags: profile, search-results

I discover the profiles, especially for the search results. Do these search profiles only work in advanced search? How do I change the look of a search on memberships, or contributions?

I have tried to create a search profile with a custom Contacts field and the Member Type field, but it does not appear in the Advanced Search Profiles drop-down list and the Membership search always displays the same result columns.

I looked at the pages of the manual but found nothing about it (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/fr/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/ and https://docs.civicrm.org/user/fr/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#personnalisation-des-ecrans-de-recherche)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The profiles are only used for contact searches.  Advanced Search lets you select a profile but you can also change the default profile (`Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Search Preferences > Default Contact Search Profile`) and that will change the results displayed from a simple search.

There are other questions on here about customising the results of contribution and membership searches which may be helpful - but it's not as simple as creating a profile.

One of the exciting new developments is SearchKit which Coleman is leading. You can build your own search for Contacts and Contributions and configure what fields to show.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnL7-GRJ_2k).  Memberships are not supported yet but SearchKit is progressing rapidly.